# How to find the integral $\int4^{-x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, exponentiation

What approach would be ideal in finding the integral $\int4^{-x}dx$?

Comment: Hint. $d/dx 4^x= 4^x\ln 4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the most Important thing here is that $(4^{-x})'=(-\ln 4)4^{-x}$

So we rewrite our integral as follows:

$\int 4^{-x}\,dx=\frac{-1}{\ln 4}\int -\ln 4\cdot 4^{-x}\,dx=\frac{-1}{\ln 4}\int (4^{-x})'\,dx=-\frac{1}{\ln 4}4^{-x}+C$.

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite the integral as $$\int e^{(- \ln 4) x} \mathrm{d}x. $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $u = -x$, then you can go from here.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int 4^{-x}\,{\rm d}x =
-\,{1 \over \ln(4)}\int\left[-\ln(4)\,4^{-x}\right]\,{\rm d}x
=-\,{1 \over \ln(4)}\int{{\rm d 4^{-x}} \over {\rm d}x}\,{\rm d}x
=-\,{4^{-x} \over \ln(4)} + \mbox{a constant}
$$